# Splitting object of nth length into one array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm given an Object of *n* length, with *x* amount of arrays in the object. I would like not to include the 0's, and to be sorted in descending order.

I've made a simple solution, that takes the value in each object, and takes the nth value and puts that in an array, but am looking for something more robust and shorter; any help would be helpful!

```js
const arr = {
  "rows": [{
    "value": "demo value 1",
    "data": [15, 45, 0, 0]
  }, {
    "value": "demo value 2",
    "data": [11, 87, 0, 0]
  }, {
    "value": "demo value 3",
    "data": [8, 113, 0, 0]
  }, {
    "value": "demo value 4",
    "data": [7, 26, 0, 2]
  }, {
    "value": "demo value 5",
    "data": [7, 3, 0, 0]
  }, {
    "value": "demo value 6",
    "data": [6, 17, 0, 1]
  }]
};

let newArr = [];
let newArr2 = [];
let newArr3 = [];
let newArr4 = [];

for (i = 0; i < arr.rows.length; i++) {
  if (arr.rows[i].data[0] != 0)
    newArr.push({
      value: arr.rows[i].value,
      data: arr.rows[i].data[0]
    })
  if (arr.rows[i].data[1] != 0)
    newArr2.push({
      value: arr.rows[i].value,
      data: arr.rows[i].data[1]
    })
  if (arr.rows[i].data[2] != 0)
    newArr3.push({
      value: arr.rows[i].value,
      data: arr.rows[i].data[2]
    })
  if (arr.rows[i].data[3] != 0)
    newArr4.push({
      value: arr.rows[i].value,
      data: arr.rows[i].data[3]
    })
  /// ... and so on
}

console.log(newArr)
console.log(newArr2)
console.log(newArr3)
console.log(newArr4)
```

**EDIT:**

Expected result:

```
[
  [
    {
      "value": "demo value 1",
      "data": 15
    },
    {
      "value": "demo value 2",
      "data": 11
    },
    {
      "value": "demo value 3",
      "data": 8
    },
    {
      "value": "demo value 4",
      "data": 7
    },
    {
      "value": "demo value 5",
      "data": 7
    },
    {
      "value": "demo value 6",
      "data": 6
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "value": "demo value 3",
      "data": 113
    },
    {
      "value": "demo value 2",
      "data": 87
    },
    {
      "value": "demo value 1",
      "data": 45
    },
    {
      "value": "demo value 4",
      "data": 26
    },
    {
      "value": "demo value 6",
      "data": 17
    },
    {
      "value": "demo value 5",
      "data": 3
    }
  ],
  [],
  [
    {
      "value": "demo value 4",
      "data": 2
    },
    {
      "value": "demo value 6",
      "data": 1
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: Have you had a look at the [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if this is what you're after as there is no "expected format" provided - however this may put you on the right track

```js
let new_arrays = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.rows.length; i++) {
    let current_row = arr.rows[i];
    for (let j = 0; j < current_row.data.length; j++) {
        let current_data = current_row.data[j];

        if(current_data === 0){
            continue;
        }

        if(new_arrays[j] === undefined){
            new_arrays[j] = [];
        }

        new_arrays[j].push({
            value: current_row.value,
            data : current_data,
        });
    }

}

console.log(new_arrays);
```

NOTE: if all values at an index are 0 (or the index doesn't exist), there will be no "new array" at that index